# tell pycharm to step over or skip functions during step in

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Is there a way to tell PyCharm to skip over specific functions when doing a "step in" during debugging python code?  For instance if I have a method somewhere like this:

```
def getHost(self):
  return self.host
```

And then elsewhere I have a function call

```
self.buggyFunction(thing.getHost())
```

There is no way to "step in" to this function without first stepping throuth getHost().  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply "step in" through your code once, and place breakpoints at all the points you would like to stop. Then when you run your code a second time you can just advance to each breakpoint and step from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for something more permanent than this. I have function calls that are multiple getters in a single line before i get to the actual function im working on. The project is fairly complicated and functions are re-entered a lot!